# Google Earth Automated Imagery Downloading for different locations

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-pro

Is there any method for Google Earth to Automate the process where we define cities and areas and we receive printable files from the most interesting spots of the cities?

Answer (score 1):

Earth Pro does have a tool to print out relatively high res images, using the "Save as Image" tool. More info at [this link](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148146).

But before you start systematically exporting imagery from Google Earth or Maps, I encourage you to read the [Terms of Service](https://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html), especially sections 2.b. and 2.c.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I have read the terms of services, so we are not allowed in this situation if we don't have the permission.